# How do I get a list of installed files from a package?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I want to know where I can find my installed application when I installed it on Ubuntu using package manager.

I installed RabbitMQ and ran `locate rabbitmq` which gave me following result:

```
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2/_maven.repositories
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2/amqp-client-1.7.2.jar
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2/amqp-client-1.7.2.jar.lastUpdated
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2/amqp-client-1.7.2.jar.sha1
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2/amqp-client-1.7.2.pom
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2/amqp-client-1.7.2.pom.lastUpdated
/home/anupamg/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/1.7.2/amqp-client-1.7.2.pom.sha1
/home/anupamg/Downloads/rabbitmq-server-generic-unix-2.4.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: What application? Some are accesible through commandline, others get an pretty icon in the application menu. Be more specific.

Comment: Do you want to know where the executables and config files reside or do you want to execute it and don't know how?

Comment: ok!!! i actually want to know that as in windows if i install application i can see it in program files similarly in ubuntu where to locate the installed application...I just installed RabbitMq and want to know where it is residing i need to configur its run.sh file

Comment: @ das_weezul :- yes I want to know all things which are done to my box when i click install from synaptic package manager ...i am a newbie on ubuntu... so any links are welcomed

Comment: One of the answers suggests the following `dpkg-query -c <package_name.deb>` You cannot do that to a deb file. I suspect the poster meant to use `dpkg-deb` with the same `params dpkg-deb -c <filename.deb>` Which lists the files as expected.

Comment: Linux packages often install files all over the place, unlike windows where it's mostly in Program Files and some in Users. This is why it's important to use a package manager, it keeps track of all these files. If you only want to find the executable you can do `which rabbitmq`.

Comment: Related: [List commands of a Debian package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394604/209677)

Answer (score 840, accepted):

To see all the files the package installed onto your system, do this:

```
dpkg-query -L <package_name>
```

To see the files a .deb file will install

```
dpkg-deb -c <package_name.deb>
```

To see the files contained in a package NOT installed, do this once (if you haven't installed [apt-file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt-file) already:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

then

```
apt-file list <package_name>
```

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/82923/how-to-list-files-of-a-debian-package-without-install) for more

Comment: As gazhay commented above, `dpkg-query -c foo.deb` fails.  But `dpkg-deb -c foo.deb` works.

Comment: Updating `apt-file` is pain.

Comment: Note that `dpkg -L` doesn't take into account files that may have been excluded with `--path-exclude=`.  It will list them even though they were not installed.

Comment: Is there a way to check this online?

Answer (score 41):

`dpkg -L <package_name>` might be the best for your immediate problem, but you might like to read the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/), which describes where different types of files live in the filesystem.

It is *not* definitive; it is just a descriptive account of the way things "mostly" are.

More specific to Ubuntu is the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/index.html), which will describe everything in enough detail. (So many of the other guides gloss over too many of the details, but this should be better.)

Answer (score 23):

if you just want a single installed package, you can find the package name

```
$ apt-cache search rabbitmq
...
librabbitmq-dev
...
```

then use dpkg --listfiles

```
$ dpkg --listfiles librabbitmq-dev
/usr/lib/x86-64/librabbit... 
. . .
```

Comment: might depend on the version but i had to use ```dpkg -L <package>```

Comment: `dpkg -L` works only on installed packages.

Answer (score 19):

The answer given by @Gilles is very useful (actually, the answer [was improved over time](https://askubuntu.com/posts/32509/revisions)).

Furthermore, I have a tip for the ones that don't want to install any auxiliary package (like the `apt-file`):

- Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/;
- Go to the **Search package directories** session;
- Insert your package name in the **Keyword** field and select **Only show exact matches**;
- Select your **distribution** and click in the **Search** button.
- Select the desirable package in the next screen;
- In the end of page, click in the **list of files** link next to your architecture name;
- The next page will show the list of files of your package.

As an example: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/multipath-tools/filelist

Comment: `curl -s https://packages.ubuntu.com/$(lsb_release -cs)/$(dpkg --print-architecture)/<<PACKAGE NAME>>/filelist | sed '1,/pfilelist/d;/<\/div>/,$d'`  :-)

Comment: Hah! Thanks for the tip. I was using `dpkg -L` on a _metapackage_ and surprised that there were so few files in it (and baffled why I had literally thousands of files that I _knew_ that belonged to that package). When I went to the Ubuntu packages directory, I immediately figured out that there were way more files beyond those in the metapackage...

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it for packages you don't have installed yet. Just change "autoconf" below for the package you are trying to get the list of files for:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
apt-get download autoconf
ar x *.deb
tar tf data.*
cd ..
rm -r tmp
```

Comment: Due to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669004/zst-compression-not-supported-by-apt-dpkg , using tar like this is useful to explore a package which isnt installed yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `synaptic-package-manager`:

[image]

Assuming that we'd like to locate the files of the autotools-dev package, under 'Quick filter' enter autotools-dev to locate it. The autotools-dev package appears automatically. Select it by clicking on it and then press 'Properties'. In the appearing dialog, select the tab 'Installed Files'.