# PCSX2 on Ubuntu

Tags: emulation, pcsx2

[PCSX2](http://pcsx2.net/)(playstation 2 emulator) won't work under Ubuntu 11.10 x64.
It worked when I was running Ubuntu 11.10 x86.

When I downloaded the [pcsx2-0.9.8-r4594-linux.tar.gz](http://pcsx2.net/files/28277) I extracted it in the home directory and run the `launch_pcsx2_linux.sh` file, it closed immediately. When I open GNOME-terminal and typed in: `./launch_pcsx2_linux.sh` I got the following error:

> ./pcsx2: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When I type `sudo apt-get install libwxbase2.8-0` it says that it is already installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A big plus here is, there is a Linux version of PCSX2, so we don't need to use WINE!

**Installation**

There are 2 ways to install pcsx2 in Ubuntu.

**Manually**

One just [download](http://pcsx2.net/files/28277) it from the pcsx2 site, extract it in your home folder, and run the `launch_pcsx2_linux.sh`(X86 only). here is the [pcsx2.desktop](http://www.eurobytes.nl/download/pcsx2.desktop) file save it in `/usr/share/applications/` or in your `/home/your username/.local/share/applications/`. Edit the file, where it says `your username` change it to your actual username, and the actual path to the binary.

**PPA**

If that is to much of a hassle for you, The [Gregory Hainaut](https://launchpad.net/%7Egregory-hainaut/+archive/ubuntu/pcsx2.official.ppa) PPA, is the official PCSX2 PPA, which supports x86 and x64 bit versions of Ubuntu. Due note that the package maintainers have stated:

> PPA doesn't allow to upload package on unsupported Ubuntu. In short it
> only remains LTS and latest version.

Copy past the following in your [gnome-terminal](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcsx2-unstable
```

If the PCSX2 doesn't work for you, try the `pcsx2-unstable` package. One thing you need to do, when configuring [PCSX2](http://pcsx2.net/), is add BIOS files. You will get a window that asks for these BIOS files. You will need to provide legal BIOS´es yourself!

> **Warning without BIOS'es you can't play the games.**

---

This video shows PCSX2 in action, in VMware, showing off the x86 version. I didn't start the game cause it didn't work well with my screen-recorder.

[PCSX2 in Ubuntu(x86/x64)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1y8dYlBWOh4)

[image: pcsx2]

**Source**

- [PCSX2 in Ubuntu(x86/x64) - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/pcsx2-under-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu 17.04 official wiki instructions**

The official wiki has installation instructions: https://github.com/PCSX2/pcsx2/wiki/Installing-on-Linux/d029dc1d29c94be3b991507069cf9ee1e82f589a#ubuntu-ppa

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcsx2
PCSX2
```

Note that the executable is horribly named `PCSX2` in all caps.

Notably, since the packages are 32-bit only, you first need the pesky:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

or else you get dependency problems with `libjack-0.116`.

Next, during the first run, you need to extract the BIOS to:

```
~/.config/PCSX2/bios
```

and select the one that matches your ISO's region.

Finally, you will also need:

- controllers with analog for many games, the keyboard is simply unbearable: https://github.com/PCSX2/pcsx2/issues/2075
- a beast of a computer. 60FPS is possible on the dev's machine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h5aSoLoAr4 but I could not achieve it on a high end laptop

Comment: Thanks! The official site instructions don't seem to mention using all caps to run it.

Comment: Thanks! The official site instructions don't seem to mention using all caps to run it.

Comment: @andDevW yes, that is ugly! You can also list a package's files with: https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package Now get ready to see your favorite PS2 game run at 2 FPS XD