# Where is cuda library located with apt-get install?

Tags: apt, cuda, paths

I installed cuda by apt-get. I need to point cuda libraries in cmake file for compilation of another library however I cannot find the CUDA path. Where is the /include and /bin paths of CUDA in such intallation?

Answer (score 2):

You can list files installed by a package using `dpkg --listfiles`. For example:

```
dpkg --listfiles cuda
```

This should find all the files the package installed, from which you can find the include files.

[How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)