# blender version install on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, blender

I installed Blender through the Software Center a while ago.  Version 2.69 was installed and I want to upgrade to the newer v 2.76.  I downloaded the program from blender.org, but now I'm stuck.  I am fairly new to linux and Ubuntu and I don't know where to go from here.

I tried to find where the copy of Blender I already have installed is located but couldn't find it.  I think I just need to copy the contexts of the new tar file to the old location, but can't find the old location.

Switching from windows to linux has been the most fun/frustration adventure I've had on the computer in 30 year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better by using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Sudo apt-get install blender
```

I installed this on Trusty Tahr and the latest version was successfully installed:

[image]

If you also wish to see the file locations from this package simply run:

```
dpkg-query -L blender
```

More details on this aspect can be [seen here...](https://askubuntu.com/q/32507/57576)

Comment: Thanks.  That got me up to the most recent version.  I stil am not clear on where these files exist, though.  This doesn't prevent me from using the program, but I sure would like to understand where these things get placed.

Comment: Good to see it worked out :). To see file locations try: `dpkg-query -L blender`