# Find absolute path for shared libraries

Tags: apt

I am new to Linux and I am trying to find the absolute path for the dependencies that are listed in one of the following commands output.

```
apt-cache showpkg "package name"
apt-cache depends "package name"
```

After executing the above commands I get a list of dependences for the package package depends on but not the path for that dependency which we can use in `ldd` to further check the shared dependencies for that package.

My question is how can I find where these libraries present in the entire system. I am using `Ubuntu 16.4`. For some reason, I have to find the further shared dependencies for the list of dependencies provided in `apt-cache showpkg` command output. Any help will be highly appreciated and Thank you in advance.

E.g.:

```
apt-cache depends lighttpd
lighttpd
  Depends: libattr1
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6
 |Depends: libgamin0
  Depends: libfam0
    libgamin0
  Depends: libldap-2.4-2
  Depends: libpcre3
  Depends: libssl1.0.0
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: init-system-helpers
  Depends: perl
 |Depends: lsb-base
  Depends: systemd
    systemd:i386
  Depends: mime-support
  Depends: libterm-readline-perl-perl
  Recommends: spawn-fcgi
  Suggests: openssl
  Suggests: rrdtool
  Suggests: apache2-utils
    apache2-utils:i386
  Suggests: ufw
```

Comment: `locate` package works perfectly in this situation but I am looking for something with already inbuild commands such as which or find.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, going over old unanswered migrated questions: Let's go a bit deeper on package dependencies and file locations:

A package is a *inventory* of collections of files (like a Table of Contents (TOC) in a book) whereas file locations are pointers to where a file resides on disk.

However, you can have the TOC, without the book(Packages without files), and you can have files without Package dependencies (E.g. a standalone script)

So if you'd only be interested in knowing the file location for the packages that are installed on the system, you'd have to do a:

- [List all packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)
- [Get a list of files in those packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)
- and then use `locate --existing` to run that list through locate (fastest, `find` will take much longer) and you have what you need!
- knowing that you might still have files without a package and packages without files (meta-packages)