# Where is nccl.h?

Tags: apt

Following [Installing NCCL](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/nccl-install-guide/index.html#down)  I install NCCL:

```
sudo apt install libnccl2=2.4.2-1+cuda10.0 libnccl-dev=2.4.2-1+cuda10.0
```

But I can't find nccl.h.

After I install NCCL, where is nccl.h?

Comment: Related: [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)

Comment: "But I can't find nccl.h" but you forgot how you search for it.

Comment: locate nccl.h doesn't find it.  find . -name 'nccl.h' will take way too long starting from the root, especially taking into account the /mnt directories.

Comment: You can add `-xdev` to prevent `find` from descending into other mounted filesystems. You can likely also root the search at `/usr/include` instead of `/`.

Comment: @empty locate is not updated immediately. you need to rebuild the database if you want newly added files from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```
sudo dpkg-query -L libnccl-dev
```

Comment: Yes this hleped me too. Ubuntu 18.04