# Where do I find UTF8PROC?

Tags: software-installation

Where do I find `UTF8PROC`? With a quick research I have found that it might be in `libutf8proc1`, so I installed it with `sudo apt install` , but the `./configure` of `subversion` still doesn't find `UTF8PROC`. Where is it?

If needed I use version 16.04

I don't think this is a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/32507/743263) question I am asking which package should I install to get the file `UTF8PROC`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)

Comment: @karel thanks but I have found a solution here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/subversion.html

Answer (score 1):

Quick search on packages.ubuntu.com [gives](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=UTF8PROC) the packages with this file.

You have to install related package with

```
sudo apt-get install libutf8proc-dev
```