# how to find the list of binaries/packages a source provides

Tags: apt, package-management, source, source-packages

We can find the source of the package with `apt show <package name>`, but how do we find the list of all binaries or packages a source provides?

For example apt show will give following information and more

```
$ apt show linux-libc-dev
Package: linux-libc-dev
Version: 4.4.0-96.119
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Source: linux
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Here the source is "linux". Similarly, I remember using a command to get all the packages from the source "linux", which gives all the binaries and packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `showsrc` subcommand of `apt` or `apt-cache`.
See `man apt-cache` or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html) for details.

Below is the output from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

> ```
> $ apt-cache showsrc linux  
> Package: linux
> Binary: linux-source-4.4.0, linux-doc, linux-headers-4.4.0-21, linux-libc-dev,
> linux-tools-common, linux-tools-4.4.0-21, linux-cloud-tools-common,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21, linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic,
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic, linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic-dbgsym, linux-tools-4.4.0-21-generic,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21-generic, linux-udebs-generic,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic-lpae,
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic-lpae,
> linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic-lpae,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic-lpae-dbgsym,
> linux-tools-4.4.0-21-generic-lpae,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21-generic-lpae, linux-udebs-generic-lpae,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-lowlatency,
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-lowlatency,
> linux-headers-4.4.0-21-lowlatency,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-lowlatency-dbgsym,
> linux-tools-4.4.0-21-lowlatency,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21-lowlatency, linux-udebs-lowlatency,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc-e500mc,
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-powerpc-e500mc, 
> linux-headers-4.4.0-21-powerpc-e500mc,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc-e500mc-dbgsym,
> linux-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc-e500mc,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc-e500mc, linux-udebs-powerpc-e500mc,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc-smp,
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-powerpc-smp,
> linux-headers-4.4.0-21-powerpc-smp,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc-smp-dbgsym,
> linux-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc-smp,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc-smp, linux-udebs-powerpc-smp,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-emb,
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-emb,
> linux-headers-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-emb,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-emb-dbgsym,
> linux-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-emb,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-emb, linux-udebs-powerpc64-emb,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-smp,
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-smp,
> linux-headers-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-smp,
> linux-image-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-smp-dbgsym,
> linux-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-smp,
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-21-powerpc64-smp,  linux-udebs-powerpc64-smp
> Version: 4.4.0-21.37
> Priority: optional
> Section: devel 
> ...
> ```

Comment: This is more detailed than what I remember using. But thank you very much, it shows all the packages when I do ```apt-cache showsrc linux``` :)

Comment: What is the sense of `Package: linux Binary:` at the end of the cmdl ? Typo?

Comment: @N0rbert we can directly write ```apt-cache showsrc linux``` also (which is actually what I wanted to know, even if we didn't know any packages in the source)