# were OGRE path?

Tags: 20.04

install [OGRE3d](https://www.ogre3d.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install libogre-1.12 libogre-1.12-dev
```

, but not going path here bild OGRE3d

```
(base) comp@comp:/lib$ cd ..
(base) comp@comp:/$ find ogre
find: ‘ogre’: Нет такого файла или каталога
(base) comp@comp:/$ find ogre3d
find: ‘ogre3d’: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

were OGRE3d bild and how integrate him in qt ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tsank @N0rbert

this work

```
 dpkg-query -L libogre-1.12-dev
```

include in program

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreBites

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreHLMS

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreMain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreMeshLodGenerator

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreOverlay

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgrePaging

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreProperty

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreRTShaderSystem

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreTerrain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOgreVolume

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/OGRE
```