# Syslinux Install Directory

Tags: server, pxe, syslinux

I installed syslinux using the following:

```
apt install -y syslinux
```

I'd like to know where it was actually installed. I can't seem to find the files anywhere. I'm trying to set up a PXE boot server on Ubuntu 22.04 server edition and need to copy these files to a tftp directory. I've logged in as sudo (using sudo -i) so am effectively root.

Comment: See [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package) - you will likely want to look at the package's immediate dependencies as well ex. `dpkg -L syslinux syslinux-common`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)

Comment: Thanks Steel,  I was trying to follow this guide where syslinux was installed and the files were placed in a discreet directory: https://www.linuxhowto.net/install-multiple-linux-distributions-using-pxe-network-boot-on-rhel-centos-8/ but adapting it to a Debian (Ubuntu) OS. "Step 2: Install SYSLINUX Bootloaders" shows the contents of the syslinux install being able to be copied to another directory. That is what I am after, a discreet folder from where the files may be copied to the tftp server directory. Regards, Matt.

Comment: Adding a comment doesn't seem to allow me to format the text and code in a logical, easily way to read as does the entering of the original comment. I apologise for this.