# How to find out what is installed in the package.deb?

Tags: package-management, deb, kali-linux-tools

How to find out what is installed in the package.deb via the command line? I'm trying to figure out if some daemon or service was installed along with the package. What command can I use to find out?

Comment: Open your package.deb in Midnight Commander.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You can use `dpkg` to view a deb file

```
dpkg --info /path/file.deb
```

to get general information, and

```
dpkg --contents /path/file.deb
```

to get the files (programs, libraries, documents etc) listed:

### Edit: You can also view a deb file with `emacs`

```
emacs /path/file.deb
```

and that way get into the different parts of the deb file

Example from `ppa:mkusb/unstable` which I am developing. The following command

```
emacs dus_22.0.7-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

brings you to a table

```
   Mode    User/Group   Size        Date       Filename
--------- -----/-----  ----- ---------------- ----------------
rw-r--r--     0/0          4 2022-06-03 17:03 debian-binary
rw-r--r--     0/0       1420 2022-06-03 17:03 control.tar.xz
rw-r--r--     0/0      58968 2022-06-03 17:03 data.tar.xz
--------- -----/-----  ----- ---------------- ----------------
```

You can enter the control tarball to see the same as `dpkg --info` and enter the data tarball to see the same as `dpkg --contents` and furthermore very conveniently enter each of the files if they are possible to read (and most of the dus files are bash shellscripts).

### Edit 2: Install `package` from `deb` file

The command line

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

should *install* `package` and make its program(s) available like other programs, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than look at deb files looking for a program (gpsd in below example), you can run:

```
apt-file search bin/gpsd
```

and get the list of packages containing your daemon.

First you would install apt-file

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then update

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Then searches will work, even on non-installed debs.

Answer (score 0):

List what files belong to a package:

```
dpkg -L packagename
```

and soon you will want the reverse command too, how to see to which package a file belongs to (if any):

```
dpkg -S /my/path/somefile
```

Both commands work only for packages which are already installed.