# python3-serial miniterm.py location

Tags: python, python3

I am trying to install python3-serial on ubuntu (18.04 and 20.04) and can't seem to get miniterm.py in PATH.

From what I've read, it should be installed either in `/usr/bin/miniterm.py` or `/usr/local/bin/miniterm.py`, but it doesn't get installed anywhere. I have tried the following:

1. `sudo apt install -y python3-serial`
2. `pip install pyserial` in a virtual environment
3. `sudo pip install pyserial` global

`which miniterm.py` returns nothing every time. I can't find it anywhere.

What do you advise?

Comment: For the first method, you may find this helpful - [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package). It looks like the executable is named `pyserial-miniterm` (`/usr/bin/pyserial-miniterm`) rather than `miniterm.py`

Comment: Thanks, ran dpkg-query -L python3-serial | grep miniterm and it seems it installs in /usr/bin/miniterm. I wonder if /usr/local/bin/miniterm.py is something from python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after fiddling around with pyserial, I have found out that, if installed using the [setup.py](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/v3.4/setup.py) script, [`miniterm.py`](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/v3.4/setup.py#L99) will be installed in `/usr/local/bin`. I have tested this for pyserial 2.7 and 3.4.

For the newest version, though, which is [3.5](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/tree/v3.5), as @steeldriver said in his comment, [`pyserial-miniterm`](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/v3.5/setup.py#L101) will be installed instead of `miniterm.py`.

When installing through apt, on ubuntu 18.04 [pyserial 3.4-2](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/python-serial_3.4-2_all.deb.html) is installed and nothing is added in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. Or maybe my setup is broken or something, I don't know. On ubuntu 20.04 [pyserial 3.4-5.1](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-arm64/python3-serial_3.4-5.1_all.deb.html) will be installed through apt and `miniterm` will be put in `/usr/bin`.

All in all, this is really confusing.